# I have a .swf file in my website

Tags: html, flash

I have a .swf file inside a website I've been asked to modify. Will this file contain normal html files and if so how do I get to them, there are no .fla file on the machine that created the site.

Thanks
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.swf file is a flash element which is "playable" by your flash player. .swf is normally created used action script. In other words, the .swf file is the compiled version of the .fla file, and you can therefore not edit the .swf file.

Answer (score 1):

Although Roskvist is completely right, there IS a way to convert .swf files back to actionscript code (and possibly .fla). This won't get you the original source code, but an 'estimated' code (with different variable names etc) that would give you pretty much the same .swf upon rendering. This can be done by software called a 'flash decompiler'.

A word of warning though: It's not okay to use this for stealing flash code from others' flash creations, you must have the rights to use any source code.